# как передать значение php файлам

Tags: php

Привет всем друзья я новичек в PHP.
у меня такая проблема нужно войти в сайт с этим проблем нет вроде проверяю вхожу но другие страницы не запоминают мой вход то есть после нажатие на ссылки я снова выхожу, как заставить его запомнить вход?
заранее спасибо

Comment: Cookie? Session? Почитайте об этих механизмах.

Comment: для каждого файла использовать Cookie или Session?

Comment: Это механизм передачи параметров между запросами, почитайте их описание, и да их использование придется прописать в каждой точке входа(в каждом файле к которому идет прямое обращение)